# Updating Jekyll and ran into 'undefined local variable or "singleton_class" for Liquid:Module (NameError)

Tags: terminal, jekyll, command-prompt

I wanted to work through a jekyll tutorial, but my previous version of jekyll was version 0.11.0. So, I attempted to upgrade. Now when I check the version, I get the following error in Terminal:

```
undefined local variable or method `singleton_class' for Liquid:Module (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/../lib/jekyll.rb:25
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/jekyll:20
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:19
```

It doesn't look like it worked...or maybe it did? Any ideas on what happened and how to fix this? (thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably because your environment doesn't meet Jekyll requirements.

> v1.9.3 or above for Jekyll 2 and v2 or above for Jekyll 3

See [Jekyll requirement](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/#requirements)